# How to convert "promises" to "string" in static methods [ts]

Tags: parsing, typescript, promise, protractor

I have a doubt about using of "promises" in typescript. I'm writting e2e testing framework with protractor and typescript and I would like to make some query to the database in order to use the data retrieved to fill forms or make validations.

I've create a new class "UserService" and the idea is to use some static methods to return data. I've installed the typeOrm library to handle it.

The problem is I cannot find the way to convert the "promise" returns to "strings". How can I do it?

Take a look to the code:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import { User } from "././entities/user";
import { ConnectionOptions, Connection, Driver, createConnection } from "typeorm";

const connectionOptions: ConnectionOptions = {
    driver: {
        type: "mysql",
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        username: "root",
        password: "admin123",
        database: "user"
    },
    entities: [User],
    autoSchemaSync: false
};

export class UserService {

    static getUserName(userId:number): string {

        let us = createConnection(connectionOptions).then(connection => { 
            return connection.getRepository(User).findOne({Id: userId})
        }).then(user => user.name);

        return us;  //it return an Promise<string>.
    }
}
```

Into the "step" classes, the above class will be used for example as:

```
let name: string = UserService.getUserName(1);
txtUsername.Sendkeys(name);
```

Comment: You're already using, twice, then then() method of the promise to execute code once a promise is resolved. Do the same here: `UserService.getUserName(1).then(name => txtUsername.Sendkeys(name));`

Comment: Indeed you cannot. It's asynchronous, you have to wait for it. `UserService.getUserName(1).then(name => txtUsername.Sendkeys(name))`

Comment: A JavaScript `class` with only static methods is very bad code.

Comment: In international English, we say "question", not "doubt".

Answer (score 1):

Use await/async:

```
let name = await UserService.getUserName(1);
txtUsername.Sendkeys(name);
```

This has to be in a function defined as async, and you'll probably want to surround it with a try/catch, and it will not be synchronous, but that's the easiest way to access it.

And have no doubts about promises... they are super awesome.